# Telethon add members to a group or channel without sending any link

Tags: python, telethon

I want to add members to my telegram channel using telethon from it's documentation we can do this using [InviteToChannelRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/invite_to_channel.html) but there is a catch: It will send my `channel link` to users who have `disabled` 'enable everyone to add them to groups from their privacy settings', which may anger them and cause them to report me, which is something I don't want.

I attempted to add subscribers to my channel using this code.

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest
import time, random, datetime


api_id = '12345'
api_hash = 'abcdefjghi'

client = TelegramClient('db/session.session', api_id, api_hash)

async def add():

    await client.start()
    channel_entity = await client.get_entity('my_channel_username')

    uname_list = ['username1', 'username2', 'userame3']

    for i, uname in enumerate(uname_list):

        try:
            await client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel_entity, [uname]))
        except Exception as err:
            with open(f"logs/{uname}_err.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(f"\n{datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d %B')} {datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')}\n")
                f.write(f"\n{err}")

    await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.loop.run_until_complete(add())
```

I want to know if there is a way to only add members that allow me to do so without sending links to others